# Visaulforce page for account team related list on accounts

Tags: visualforce

I have created a vf page for displaying acocunt team members related list on account.
I have implemented the add and delete functionality.
in one page block i am adding the records and when i click save it appears in the bottom page block section
now when it is saved in the bottom pageblock section i want it to disappear from the first pageblock section
how will that happen

Comment: Clear the fields and rerender the section? Unfortunately without seeing your code not much can be suggested.